# Is this a cashier check scam?

Tags: fraud, wire-transfer, cashier-check, foreign

I'm a personal trainer and I've received an email stating that someone wants me to train their kids while they are in the US for vacation. The request was for many sessions and would total well over $1000

The part I am concerned about is that the father asked me to send my address, full name, and phone number. He promised that his secretary would send out the cashier check and I would receive it before their arrival.

I'm pretty skeptical because the English grammar in the e-mail is non-standard by any means, name seems fake, an overseas client, and very shaky details... is there any danger in me giving out my information or accepting/cashing this check? I don't see what they have to gain/scam from this if they're not asking me to send them anything. He is asking me to send him all this information ASAP.

Thoughts on this?

Much appreciated!

Comment: Have you had contact with the people you are supposed to train?

Comment: Not personally, they texted my business number and asked me to email them. They then said they will arrive in the country in several weeks.

Comment: @Leo typical scenario for these types of scams. I once put myself out on some education tutoring website and had almost the same exact scenario play out. They had a daughter in the US who they wanted me to tutor. They were going to pay upfront. They can't be contacted because they were outside the US, blah blah blah.  And they basically asked for my address, name, phone, and other info. They didn't even ask me about my qualifications or anything.

Answer (score 3):

Scam:

https://www.facebook.com/dbhit/posts/scam-alertif-you-are-a-personal-trainer-or-studio-owner-and-have-received-the-fo/840305396033681/

https://tbianchino.wordpress.com/2016/03/11/fitness-pros-new-e-mail-scam/

Tip: If you are personal trainer and suspect a scam google "personal trainer scam"

Comment: In my personal experience whenever someone has their "secretary" send payment for some service or product you personally sell, they will almost always say "oops, they sent to much, please send $XX back." Then the first check bounces and you're out $XX.